# Access the last git command output in fugitive

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

Is there any way to see the git output produced by the most recent git
command using vim-fugitive?

I know that there is :Git! but this is only useful if you know that
you want to see results of a command before you issue it.

What do I do if I issued, say :Gpull, then vim shown no output, and I
would, just in case, like to see what was the git command output, after
I have called pull? (of course doing :Git! pull does not help, as the
subsequent pull will produce a different output).

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:Gpull` will populate the quickfix window with the results of the pull. Use `:copen` to open the quickfix window and see the results. The quickfix window will automatically open if there are errors with the pull and/or you can use the quickfix commands to navigate the quickfix list.

- `:copen` to open the quickfix window
- `:cclose` to close the quickfix window
- `:cnext`/`:cprev` to move to the next/previous item

Personally I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin to navigate the quickfix list.

For more information see:

```
:h :Gmerge
:h :Gpull
:h quickfix
:h :cope
```

Note: `:Gpull` has been changed to [`:G pull`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/9fadd7a7780f38d1b8666d5b5f497fbcd46952eb/doc/fugitive.txt#L704). The same goes for merge, fetch, and push, etc.